# Using Uglify with TypeScript and Webpack 2

Tags: typescript, webpack-2

I'm a beginner with Webpack 2, and I'm trying to set up a build that transpiles TypeScript to JavaScript and minifies the JavaScript with Uglify. But I don't know how to set this in webpack.config.js. Here's my attempt:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "./app.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.ts/,
        loader: "awesome-typescript-loader!tslint-loader"
      },
      {
        enforce: "post",
        test: /.js/,
        loader: "uglify-loader"
      }      
    ]
  }
};
```

I'd hoped that the "post" rule would be executed after the JavaScript was generated. But the Uglify loader isn't being called at all.

Answer (score 0):

It should be done by plugin instead of loader.
Described here https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/

You should add plugin to your config

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {...},
  output: {...},
  module: {...},
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin()
  ]
};
```